# Using APC's PowerNet MIB to plot custom sensors in smokeping or cacti

Tags: snmp, mib, cacti

(This problem is not about using custom MIB files with pysnmp.)

I want to monitor some UPSs and ACs that provide SNMP status using APC's PowerNet MIB. I have chosen the OIDs to monitor. Now I need to configure  preferably smokeping but possibly cacti to collect in RRDBs and plot as usual.

I can install the PowerNet MIB and use snmpwalk with suitable command line flags to view all the sensors I need. I have also used pysnmp to access these from Python and update these into RRDBs and plot charts.

But what I want is to add some config files into smokeping or cacti so these gadgets and their sensors are included uniformly into what smokeping or cacti already displays for the data center. I can also add some code to smokeping or cacti provided no rebuild is needed.

I am on Debian testing kernel 4.19.28-2 with smokeping == 2.7.3-2 and cacti == 1.2.2+ds1-2.